How to generate similar videos below the current playing video on a page
I'm currently working on a video player page for a website project. I've successfully set up the JavaScript to display a specific video using a URL in this format: 'website.html?videoId=videotoplay'. However, I'm facing a challenge in displaying related videos below the main video based on matching tags. Each video has associated tags stored in an array in my JavaScript, and I need to find a way to iterate through the tags and display the videos with matching tags below the main video.
Below is my current JavaScript code 
const allVideos = [
  {
    id: "video1",
    title: "Video 1",
    preview: "video1-preview.jpg",
    url: "video URL goes here",
    tags: ["action", "adventure"]
  },
  {
    id: "video2",
    title: "Video 2",
    preview: "video2-preview.jpg",
    url: "video URL goes here"
    tags: ["thriller", "mystery"]
  },
];

function getUrlParameter(name) {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  return urlParams.get(name);
}

function loadVideoPage() {
  const videoId = getUrlParameter('videoId');
  const mainVideo = allVideos.find(video => video.id === videoId);
  if (mainVideo) {
 // Load the main video
    const mainVideoElement = document.getElementById('main-vid');
    mainVideoElement.src = mainVideo.url;
// Set the video title
    const videoTitleElement = document.querySelector('.vid-name');
    videoTitleElement.textContent = mainVideo.title;
// Update the tags
    document.getElementById('tags').dataset.tags = mainVideo.tags.join(',');

//Calling the load 
loadVideoPage();

I'll like the videos matched to the tag of the playing video to be appended to the below html (by that I mean the preview image from the above array and the title).
<div id="suggest-video">
    <Img>preview image</img>
    <P>title</p>
</div>

The img and p tags will be generated add filled with JavaScript.
It's a hassle I know , but please I couldn't have gotten this far without the much help I've received any. Any and every help will be highly appreciated . Thank you.

Use allVideos.filter() with a callback function that checks whether the tags include the tag you're searching for.

Create a div with class "other-vids" and put the code below inside the if(mainImage) statement:
  const otherVideoContainer = document.querySelector(".other-vids");
  //Find all videos which are not the main video and have at least one tag in common with the main video
  const otherVidsWithMatchingTag = allVideos.filter(vid=>vid.id !== mainVideo.id && mainVideo.tags.some(tag=>vid.tags.includes(tag)));
    otherVidsWithMatchingTag.forEach((vid)=>{

        //Create a div with suggest-video class
        const otherVid = document.createElement("div");
        otherVid.classList.add("suggest-video");

        //Add an image with vid preview as src to the div
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = vid.preview;
        otherVid.appendChild(img);

        //Add the paragraph with the title to the div
        const title = document.createElement("p");
        title.innerText = vid.title;
        otherVid.appendChild(title);

        //Add the div to the otherVideoContainter
        otherVideoContainer.appendChild(otherVid);
    })

It finds all videos which have different id than the current video but contain at least one of the tags of the current video in their taglist. Then it creates the div element with the preview and the title for all these videos and appends these divs to be children of the other-vids div.

Thank you so much, this fixed everything
